# SystemVerilog: Is there a way to get a reg delayed by more than 1 clock cycles in one line?

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

I have a bunch of signals that I want to delay by x number of cycles so I can easily debug the signals in waveform. Basically I want to make signals for different units aligned together.

I know you can do it this way but that's writing two lines per signal ignoring the for loop and always. Is there a way to do it in 1 line per signal?

```
logic [3:0] a
logic [3:0] a_delayed [0:X-1]


always @(posedge clk) begin
  a_delayed[0] <= a;
  for(int i=1; i<X;i++)
    a_delayed[i] <= a_delayed[i-1];
end
```

Edit: Another option is to implement a submodule that performs shift register but I am looking for an option with 1 module only.

Comment: If you were only looking to do this in your simulation waveform window, most tools have a way of displaying time shifting values.

Comment: you can always \`define a macro with arguments to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an unpacked array concatenation

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  a_delayed <= {a, a_delayed[0:X-2]};
end
```

Comment: Oh I forgot about the unpacked array concatenation. That will save a few lines.

Comment: However, this is not exactly what I was looking for because it needs an unpacked array. I was looking into a solution that only uses the initial and final signal. Unpacked arrays don't get loaded in the waveform by default in the simulator I am using. I guess this can't be done in Systemverilog directly.